# How can I get 100 integers but exclude some numbers?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have a task: I need to number 100 apartments in a building, but they should not have numbers 3 and 5 (13, 15, 23, 25 and so on). So there will be apartments with numbers 101, 104 etc. The problem is I should only use cycles (for or while) and if statement to do it.

```
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i / 10 == 3 || i % 10 == 3 || i / 10 == 5 || i % 10 == 5) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
```

It's clumsy, and I have only numbers UP TO 100 and not 100. Overall, I now have only 63 apartments numbered

Comment: have your counter only augment if you add a number. don't use the counter as a number to add, but use a separate one

Comment: instead of a for loop, use a while loop that terminates when the counter reaches 100. i can be incremented inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not test condition by `i` but `counter`:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 1; counter < 100; i++) {
    if (i / 10 == 3 || i % 10 == 3 || i / 10 == 5 || i % 10 == 5) {
        continue;
    } else {
        ++counter;
        System.out.println(counter + ": " + i);
    }
}
```

P.S. I used the if condition as is, but it has another problem.

Comment: BTW no need for `continue` since using `else`...